# MySql correct SELECT statement

Tags: mysql

I have two tables,

The first one:

```
things                descriptions
------                ------------
First thing           First description
Second thing          Second description
Third thing           Third description
Fourth thing          Fourth description

...
```

The second one:

```
id       products
--       --------
1        First product
2        Second product
3        Third product
4        Fourth product

...
```

I need a query to display the first two rows from the first table and then the first row of the second one, then the second two rows from the first table, then the second row of the second one and so on, obtaining this:

```
things+id            prod+descr
---------            ----------
First thing          First description
Second thing         Second description
1                    First product
Third thing          Third description
Fourth thing         Fourth description
2                    Second product

...
```

How can I do it? Maybe with a UNION? Thank you very much!

Comment: how many row you have to "union" ?

Comment: How would you identify which of the rows is the "first" row? or the "first two" rows? Without an ORDER BY clause, there is no guarantee that any particular row would be returned as the "first" row. Once you get that worked out, then you can write a statement to "interleave" the results from the two statements. But that will require some ugly SQL, which I wouldn't do unless there is some compelling reason this has to be done in a SQL statement.

Comment: Maybe the example nature of the example is clouding the goal, but *why* would you want to do this?

Comment: It's not really important to identify which of the rows is the first: the second table contains products to publicize placing them on the screen between the lines of the first table. A user makes a search among the records of the first table and I want to display a result of the second every two of the first.. I'm using PHP to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to me like the best practice here is to add another column to your first table that is a FK matching the PK of your first table.  Would it be acceptable to have data like this?  Then retrieve it in a program?

```
t2.ID  t2.prod     t1.thing      t1.desc
------ -------     --------      -------------
1      first prod  first thing   first desc
1      first prod  second thing  second desc
```

UPDATE: based on your needs

```
 // setup count 
 $countOuter = 0;
 $countInner = 0;

 //connect
 $mysqli = mysqli_connect(localhost,user,pass,database);

 // heres the tricky part you will have to make sure that your 
 // tables are filled out at a ratio of 2:1  or there could be an 
 // error thrown 

 // not sure if this is going to be necessary for your purposes
 $sqlTest = "select * from tableOne"
 $sqlTest2 = "select * from tableTwo"     
 $result1 = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sqlTest) or die (mysqli_error($mysqli));
 $result2 = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sqlTest2) or die (mysqli_error($mysqli));
 $rowsTableOne = mysqli_num_rows($result1);
 $rowsTableTwo = mysqli_num_rows($result2);

 // check ratio 
 if(($rowsTableOne / $rowsTableTwo) == 2) 
{

     while($countOuter < $rowsTableOne)
     {
      //outer query 
      $sqlOuter = "select * from tableOne LIMIT 2";
      if ($count % 2 == 0) {
       $sqlOuter .= " OFFSET ".$count;
      }
       $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sqlOuter) or die (mysqli_error($mysqli));    
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM))
      {        
          echo "<p>".$row[0]."&nbsp;".$row[1]."</p>";
          $countOuter++;
      }

      $sqlInner = "select * from tableTwo LIMIT 1";
      if ($countInner != 1) {
       $sqlInner .= " OFFSET ".$countInner;
      }
      $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sqlInner) or die (mysqli_error($mysqli));    
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM))
      {        
          echo "<p>".$row[0]."&nbsp;".$row[1]."</p>";
          $countInner++;
      }
     }
}
```

This should give you some general ideas, I did not have time to test it but it should point you in the general direction.

Comment: The second table contains products to publicize placing them on the screen between the lines of the first table. A user makes a search among the records of the first table and I want to display a result of the second every two of the first.. I'm using PHP to do that

Comment: What kind of program is the user using. Ie what is the language you are using to handle the data. Are you expecting the user to know sql or are you using a c# program, php ?

Comment: Then making a fk in the first table is the best way to preserve the integrity of what you are ting to do. You manipulate the output of the sql in your php mysqli  loop

Comment: Thx for your answers :) the problem is that the first table records have nothing to do with those of the second .. the first table can have hundreds of records, the second much less, I need a way to display on the screen in php ( with a while loop ) a record of the second every two / three of the first, until the end of the first table

Comment: I am lost here, if the two tables have no relation what is the logic that determines if you see the second table 2 or 3 lines from each other?

Comment: My idea was a while loop that reads and prints all the records in the first table and a counter that is incremented each time a record is printed, if the counter is divisible by two without remainder, then prints out a value from the second table getting something like this: recordFromFirstTable, recordFromFirstTable, recordFromSecondTable, recordFromFirstTable, recordFromFirstTable, recordFromSecondTable, ......

Comment: You will likely need two sql statement loops wrapped in a larger loop.  I will try and post something, but not likely till monday

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll try this evening!